# RabbitMQ: Is it possible to delete queues when they are empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

Ideally I'd like to delete queues in RabbitMQ when they become empty. Basically, I'd like a queue to be contain a backlog of messages and then when something happens, those messages will get sent off until the queue is empty. Once the queue is empty, I'd like to delete this.

Is this possible? I'm using Node.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A RabbitMQ queue can be declared such that it will be automatically deleted if there are no consumers attached to it. You can also specify a Time-To-Live value for which time the queue will be left alive even if there are no consumers. More information is here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html (look for Queues) and here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl

Since your question is tagged `javascript`, you may be using squaremo's amqplib library. Here is how you could declare your queue appropriately using that library:

```
var queueType = {durable: false, autoDelete: true, exclusive: false,
    arguments : {
        'x-message-ttl' : messageTTL,
        'x-expires' : queueTTL
    }
};

channel.assertQueue (qname, queueType_Shared)
```

More information on sqmaremo's amqplib is here: http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/doc/channel_api.html

Comment: Does "no consumers attached to it" also mean "the queue finished acking all of its messages"? What if all the worker consumers disconnected but there are still messages left to be processed in the queue? Would the queue get deleted and all of the messages lost?

Comment: Down vote because the question asked "When the queue is empty".  This is a fantastic answer for a time and connection auto delete queue.